# What are the possible consequences of clicking on a link?

Tags: virus

Presuming I'm not going to go enter my credit card details or passwords in, not going to go download anything and execute it etc.

Is it possible to actually get a virus or have something else bad happen just by going to a website?

Also, presume I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Remember Xupiter? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xupiter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I get a virus or trojan from visiting a website?](http://superuser.com/questions/106809/why-can-i-get-a-virus-or-trojan-from-visiting-a-website)

Answer (score 2):

Possible consequences? Well, that is a very broad question.

You could click on a link which downloads an executable or a program embedded in a picture which gets run via a buffer overflow.  So using the worst case: Goodbye to all information stored on your computers (including passwords if you let the browser remember them) and hello key logger (for everything you type after clicking).

Mind you, that was worst case. But I think it fits the question as asked.

Comment: @OP: Keep in mind that Google Chrome attempts to identify dangerous websites and warn you before entering them ("This site may harm your computer" page).